# Find words in document SP URL

Tags: c#, console-application, openxml-sdk

I have a sample code, it works well if the document is locally, but if I point the way to the link, then immediately the error, how to win?

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using OpenXmlPowerTools;

using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"http://sp-test/sites/test/Documents/Base.docx", true))
TextReplacer.SearchAndReplace(wordDoc: doc, search: "Tags", replace: "Test", matchCase: false);
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
>   occurred in DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not find document

Comment: Is this a console application or web application?

Comment: Console application is error and Web application is empty, document is not change.

Comment: You need to retrieve the document from SharePoint with any authorized connection and then you can process it with OpenXML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`WordprocessingDocument.Open` looks for the `fileHandle` or `Stream` but you are providing `URL` which doesn't make sense.

you first need to use HttpClient to download file as `Stream` then process it with 
`WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream)` accordingly